# Forms not supported in AMP

Tags: java, ajax, forms, amp-html

I have search functionality with form. Use `method="post"` but its not working gives "amp" error that invalid attribute "action".

I have also tried "`action-xhr`" but still its not working. Please if anyone has solution let me know.

This is my code:

```
<form method="post" action-xhr="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Search"> 
    <div class="input-group col-md-5 col-xs-6"> 
        <input type="text" name="proname" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Find Courses..." /> 
        <span class="input-group-btn"> 
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg searchBtnBorder"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> </button> 
        </span> 
    </div> 
</form>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Please show some code what you have tried.

Comment: Please put your code in question section and update your question, not in the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using https in your action link? AMP forms must all be https

So you will need to use a full path and have SSL Cert installed

```
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form

"Action must be provided, https"
```

If you use method "GET" you don't need to use https. Also, you must have target set to "_top" or "_blank" otherwise you won't validate.